# Do I need a 32 bit operating system?

Tags: drivers, sound, 64-bit, pulseaudio, installed-programs

I am brand new to Ubuntu, & been working with computers since DOS 4.  I like to record bands and have all the software and hardware necessary for 32 track recording. However it seems to me windows attitude is “We don’t care if your hardware is only 5 years old and works with out fault. We are going to redesign windows so you have to repurchase everything if you want to play!”

I think only 32 bit drivers are available and will have to use windows 32 bit drives with Ubuntu.  Is this correct?

I am aware driver states good for 64 bit but the hundreds of people like me that use multiple cards have not found solution that works.

I also have idea many windows programs (Sonar Producer)will run on Ubuntu.  Is this correct?

I am hoping to end up with OS that will allow secure access to internet and work with the many software options necessary for creating music.

My sound cards (M-Audio delta 1010 x4) were designed long before 64 bit was usable. There is something in driver tells OS these 4 are one.

Also until Win 7 I always had option to be able to choose between many sound cards and never had problem running media player with recording software Sonar Producer.

Only updated drivers I have found are available through M-Audio and only work for 1 card.  If you have two, the internal ad/da converter timing signal does not lock and this is serious problem from windows 7 on. I have been able to duplicate the problem on XP by manually configure IRQ settings the way windows 7 does placing onboard motherboard sound card IRQ with M-audio card 1.

I am open for suggestions and Thank you; Dave

Comment: What model of CPU do you have? How much RAM do you have?

Comment: Please restructure your question so the details of your issues can be at the top while the question at the bottom, a suggestion though!